# Install a recessed medicine cabinet with stud problems

Tags: drywall, carpentry

I have a space determined for a recessed medicine cabinet.  When I cut a peephole in the drywall, I determined that the closest stud on the left is 6" from the left edge of the recessed area.  On the right there's only a 1/4 of a stud that goes part way down from the ceiling...which would only match about 5 or 6" of where the cabinet would be going...and its about 4.5" from where the edge of the cabinet would be going on the right side anyway.

A friend recommended just screwing 2x4/shims face to face with the studs until it was flush with the opening (after extending the 1/4 stud to make it easier).  I wonder if there is a better option or if this option would be stable/sturdy enough?

Comment: If all else fails, you could frame it as you would a window (cripple studs and so on).

Comment: Just a heads up, there will probably be pipes for the sink below the medicine cabinet, I would look first, and if so, be careful- don't accidentlaly drop any 2x4s in the wall.

Comment: I can't really frame it in like a window because I can't access the studs directly (do to it already being drywalled).  I only have the  approx 18x13 hole for the medicine cabinet.  Also I checked for pipes below, its actually a drywall bump out so that's not a problem.

Comment: Maybe a surface mount cabinet would be a better (and certainly easier) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hearing that you don't want to cut out drywall, install bridge framing between studs, put your previously removed drywall back in, spackle, prime & re-paint. Well, this Medicine Cabinet better be 24" wide or less.

If so, then you can simply screw through the drywall into your new framing sticks. Do this from both sides of the wall for optimal strength & support. Or, turn the 2x4's flat against the bath wall & install 2 rows of screws to secure them.

You'll want your top & bottom pieces longer so you can toenail the side up & down on the left side. The right side will be a little funky, but that's not entirely your fault. Finally, you can frame the Medicine cabinet like a picture to hide all of your short-cutting wall damage.

Comment: So face nailing/screwing the 2x4 to the existing/repaired stud is not a good option?

Comment: Sure, though that's a lot of stacking & then you're still stuck on the right side though. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Measure from your closet stud on either side to the other. Take that number and subtract it from your drop-in cabinet. No take that difference and split it in half; the sum will be how many inches you'll need to shim if you have the cabinet square in the first place. If you have something smaller then a 2×4. Left over (say the distance is 5 inches) obviously a single stud shim will not work you have a few different options: rip a 2×4 length wise to the desired measurement. Or use 1× 2. Either o which are safe since it's only a medicine cabinet. Just get the thing square and plum. Use a level and double check your measurements before you cut. It's a finished wall not the most fun to repair if you like a seamless wall. If the depth of the wall isn't as deep as the cabinet your reveal may be funny looking.